# Loading Text from a file into a Text box

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, listbox, streamreader

I am trying to load a text file into a `textbox`. The file that is to be loaded is selected from a Listbox `UnViewed_Messages` however when I try and load the file it does nothing.

The code used to populate the list box is below:

```
public Quarantine_Messages()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //loads in files to the list box on load
        DirectoryInfo DirFiles = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\User\***\Documents\Noogle system\Quarantin_Messages");
        FileInfo[] Files = DirFiles.GetFiles("*.txt");
        foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
        {
            UnViewed_Messages.Items.Add(file.Name);
        }
    }
```

This is the code I am using to try and load the text file into the textbox `Message_Viewer`

```
 private void Open_Message_Content_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //tries to read in the file to the text box Message_Viewer
        string[] Files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\User\***\Documents\Noogle system\Quarantin_Messages");
        foreach (string file in Files)
        {
            if (System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file) != UnViewed_Messages.SelectedItems.ToString())
            {
                using (var viewer = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(file)))
                {
                    Message_Viewer.Text = viewer.ReadToEnd();
                    viewer.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error/issue you are running into?

Comment: The issue is that the text from the file does not appear in the text box when the `Open_Message_Content_Click` is initialised as I would like it

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger to see what Message_Viewer.Text is being set to? That may give you insight as to whether it is a File IO issue or a Binding issue

Comment: Notably you're overwriting `Message_Viewer.Text` in each turn in the foreach-loop.

Comment: Run debugger and why the !=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this maybe:

```
    private FileInfo[] files;
    private DirectoryInfo directory;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\smelendez\downloads");
        files = directory.GetFiles("*.txt");
        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(file.Name);
        }
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedFile = files[listBox1.SelectedIndex];

        richTextBox1.Text = "";
        richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(selectedFile.FullName);
    }
```

And then continue from there with whatever logic you need.

Comment: This is what i was looking for. Can i ask quickly it might seem like a daft question but why is it that i cant use variables and strings declared within the `public Quarantine_Messages()` function?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, the answer would be because of scoping. You are out of scope outside of the function, so they are not accessible. You would have to have a variable defined outside the function (for example, giving it val '123' for an int). Then in another function, that variable can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your streamreader, just use:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
Message_Viewer.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines)
```

Thats all. C#/.NET I/O is really clean if you know the stuff.

Edit: Keep in mind that with really big files, you would still have to use a filestream to read and add line by line, but it really shouldn't be a problem. I mean fill your ram with lines of text and then we talk again, okay?

[MSDN File-I/O](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.io.file.readalllines(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: if the txt file is big this will load the contents into memory. also your link is in German.

Comment: Since he is adding the text to a textbox, I assume it can't be that big. Elsewise your right ofcourse.

Comment: ReadAllLines returns an array of strings. I join them with a newline, so it can be displayed in a multiline-textbox. readAllLines doesn't return linebreaks.

Comment: @Mafii Again - ReadAllText does that

Comment: Can you leave me an explanation or Link of some sort?